# 'Column compare' conditional formatting

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013, conditional-formatting

How can I compare two 5,000+ record columns and color format them?

Example, `If value in cell Ax = Bx then cell Cx color = green`.

I can do this for one row, but to manually do it for 5000+ records seem crazy, I KNOW THERE IS ANOTHER WAY, but I can't figure out how!

If I use format painter, it copies the format of that cell, for example ($A1 = $B1), I need $A4599 = $B4599 and so forth.

Answer (score 1):

You are lucky because very easily! Please select ColumnC and HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=$A1=$B1
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select green, OK, OK.

Answer (score 0):

Just drag the cell from the bottom right and it will apply them correctly.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I would do it this way, you create a column that computes the difference between the two columns then you test the difference if it's zero or not and apply the conditional formatting on the test column.

Please note that the color of the font has been changed to match cell's background.

Credits: [tut on how to highlight rows with conditional formatting](https://excel0.com/examples/percentage-change-formula-excel/)